# How to perform SELECT query on concatenated columns in RoomDB?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a table(user) with the structure

```
+-----+----------+------------+
|ID   |firstName |lastName    |
+-----+----------+------------+
|1    |John      |Wesley      |
+-----+----------+------------+
|2    |Ashley    |Copper      |
+-----+----------+------------+
```

Search query 'n W' should results 'John Wesley' and 'y C' should results 'Ashley Copper' out fo the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer,

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ((firstName||" "||lastName)  LIKE %query%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:-

```
Select firstName,lastName from user where (firstName like "%y" and lastName like "C%") or (firstName like "%n" and lastName like "W%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query on your Room Dao method -

`SELECT user.firstName || user.lastName AS 'FULL_NAME' FROM User;`